# Parsing JavaScript MySQL response

Tags: javascript, html

Am reading MySQL via javascript,

and am getting response back successfully and returning data

But my question is that how can i parse and get only

whats your first school

from this output

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Result": [
    {
      "question": "whats your first school"
    }
  ]
}


<html>
<head>
    <title>MySqlJs test</title>
</head>
<script src="http://mysqljs.com/mysql.js"></script>
<body>
<pre id="output"></pre>
<script>
    MySql.Execute(
        "host",
        "serv", 
        "pwd", 
        "db56", 
        "select quest from datab", 
        function (data) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,null,2);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're JSON.stringifying your output but you aren't parsing it, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse, once it is parsed you'll use traditional JS traversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a JavaScript object (If it's a string use `JSON.parse()`) you can access it like:

```js
const data = {
  "Success": true,
  "Result": [{
    "question": "whats your first school"
  }]
}

console.log(data.Result[0].question);
```

Comment: thanks its working, but i can;t send this output to html via id, like document.getElementById("output") coz its console.log(data.Result[0].question);

Comment: @JeffDocm assign innerHTML = data.Result[0].question;